# How did they achieve the Gunslinger's shining eye effect in Westworld?

Tags: film-techniques, effects, westworld

[*Westworld*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070909/) was released in 1973. Back in time, the movie-making resources were so limited.

How did they achieve the [Gunslinger](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070909/characters/nm0000989)'s eye shining effect?

[image: Gunslinger, interpreted by Yul Brynner.]

Is it a kind of contact lens?

Is there more information about this (*making-of*, documentaries, etc.)?

Comment: "*Back in time, the movie-making resources were so limited.*"  People were smarter and more clever than you think they were.

Comment: @RonJohn - Gotta love when we tend to think of ourselves as so much better now, yet modern technology is such an enormous crutch...

Comment: I wish all sociopaths were this easy to spot.

Comment: @RonJohn please don't get me wrong. I'm talking about resources, not intelligence. There is no doubt that ancient people who calculated the Earth's size without any device it's tremendous smart. Actually, the lack of resources makes the achievement even more fantastic. Don't you think?

Comment: @DaniloGuimaraes I suppose, but think about it from the perspective of someone in the 1970s. Movies were not new. They had been around for 50+ years. In the 70s, they had *amazing* technology for special effects, WAY better than way back in the 10s and 20s when movie-making resources were "so limited".

Comment: @DaniloGuimaraes 1973 wasn't that long ago... we're the ones who have **forgotten how to do things without computers**.

Comment: @DaniloGuimaraes For what it’s worth, I think it’s plainly clear that you aren’t insinuating anything about the intelligence of people in the past, nor are you suggesting that we are better now than we were in the past. It’s an objective fact that in comparison to today, movie making resources were limited in 1973.

Comment: @only_pro If you think that's amazing, you should check out the "making-of" extras on the *Aliens* director's cut DVD.  The alien queen and Ripley's powerloader were both actually that size, with people inside them, steered like puppets by a dozen muscular guys each.  The film version uses a lot of close-ups which don't need so much puppetry, but the director's cut has an extended version of the fight where they break and stalk round each other.  However good digital SFX is today, I don't think any creature since then has ever been as thoroughly convincing.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Is it a kind of contact lens? Is there more information about this (making-of, documentaries, etc.)?

Yes, they used mirrored (light reflecting) contact lenses.

From this [edited version of Shooting Westworld by Michael Crichton](http://www.putlearningfirst.com/br/westworldshoot.html#anchor1075725)

> Three problems were especially tricky. One was the robot eyes. I wanted eyes that looked only slightly unreal, not strikingly bizarre. After some experimentation, **we settled on eighty percent reflectant mirrored contact lenses, which gave us flexibility to control the "kick" by lighting. They also had the virtue of permitting the actors to see through them.**

Also from [Oohlo article](http://oohlo.com/2016/10/02/here-are-a-few-interesting-tidbits-about-the-original-westworld-to-get-you-ready-for-the-hbo-series/),

> You might notice (especially in the header picture) a particular glow in the Gunslinger’s eyes (Cylon red spine, anyone?). That is no digital effect; Brynner wore mirrored (light reflecting) contact lenses.

Comment: A few years earlier, the second pilot of the original Star Trek series, "Where No Man Has Gone Before" used a cruder version of the technique: aluminum foil sandwiched between two contact lenses, with a hole poked through the center for visibility. They were uncomfortable and left the actors looking in odd directions in many shots.

Comment: People slag off actors for having it easy, but you wouldn't catch me sticking a lump of tin foil in my eye and hoping for the best

Comment: Same lenses from Pitch Black, aren't they?